# Difference equations and Matlab (some working)

Tags: matlab, recurrence-relations

The difference equations below model the yearly populations of wolves and moose, measured in hundreds. The wolves kill the moose for food.

$$\begin{align}
x_n&=x_{n-1}-0.004x_{n-1}+0.002x_{n-1}y_{n-1}\\
y_n&=y_{n-1}+0.005y_{n-1}-0.010x_{n-1}y_{n-1}-0.001y_{n-1}^2
\end{align}$$

I think I've worked out what $x$ and $y$ are correctly.

$x_n$ is predator and $y_n$ is prey. I say this because the $x_n$ has a growth term

$$+ 0.002 x_{n-1}y_{n-1}$$

…which says that $x_n$ grows by interaction between $x$ and $y$. This is classic predation a.k.a. eating prey.

The $y$s have what looks like logistic growth:

$$y_{n-1} - 0.001y^2_{n-1}$$

which says this species has a population growth that is limited by the environment.

However, does anyone know what Matlab commands I would enter to answer this question?

If there are initially $50$ wolves and $300$ moose, use Matlab to obtain plot of $x$ and $y$ versus n on the same graph, for $0 \le n \le 10000$. Remember that $x$ and $y$ are measured in hundreds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write it in this way:

```
 x(1) = 50;
 y(1) = 200;
 for n=2:10001
      x(n) = x(n-1) - 0.004*x(n-1) + 0.002*x(n-1)*y(n-1);
      y(n) = y(n-1) + 0.005*y(n-1) - 0.010*x(n-1)*y(n-1) - 0.001*(y(n-1))^2;
 end
 plot(1:10001,x);
 hold all;
 plot(1:10001,y);
```

Comment: Thank you. Have I defined x and y correctly, though?

Comment: @LauraAnderson Where did you define $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: Preallocate those arrays!

Comment: I've plotted it but the plot doesn't look right. It should be wavy. Remember that x and y are in hundreds. What should I do to edit my Matlab commands?

Comment: @LauraAnderson Since you said we should plot it for $0 \leq n \leq 10000$, the plot doesn't look nice, because x and y converges for almost $n\geq1500$. If you plot it for $0 \leq n \leq 100$ it will look better.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know by any chance how I can calculate the fixed points of the model? http://imgur.com/jV3v06Y

Comment: what do you mean by fixed points? convergence points? or the point where x and y plots cross each other?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FixedPoint.html

Comment: @LauraAnderson I know what is fixed point. But here what is the function and what is the variable to be equal?

Comment: @LauraAnderson Re fixed points, set $x_n=x_{n-1}$, $y_n=y_{n-1}$, and solve.